# Fixed header bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using the following classes to fix a header: navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top

This works perfectly on my PC:

[image: schermafbeelding 2015-12-16 om 12 20 21]

But when checking it on iPhone or iPad, the header is only partially shown:

[image: img_3292]

I'm using Bootstrap v3.3.6. Has anybody had this problem and were you able to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried resizing the browser on the pc to see where it goes wrong. If the layout is different there then on mobile you might need to add a meta tag.

Try adding this into your header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

Comment: Like I said, it works perfectly on my PC, I can't resize on my iPad, I'm already using the viewport meta tag.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this using browserstack and it looks fine to me.  Maybe it's a particular version of Safari Mobile browser not working or something cached on your phone?

[image]

Comment: It also show wrong on my Android device, so it's not an iPhone thing.